# Method of controller is not called from ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I m building a simple web application using SpringBoot.
So I build a simple html form to send username and password on Controller side.
This is the login.html page

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th=http://www.thymeleaf.org
      xmlns:sec=http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security
      xmlns:shiro=http://www.pollix.at/thymeleaf/shiro xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
   alert("pippo");

    console.log("chiamata ");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/loginsubmit",
      user: {
        username: "michele.castriotta",
        password: "password"
      }/*,
      success: function(msg) {
        console.log(mgs);
        alert(msg);
      }*/
    });
  });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login screen</h1>

<form:form action="loginsubmit" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <p>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /> </p>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller .java class:

```
package it.easyEuc.springsecuritycustomlogin;
import it.easyEuc.springsecuritycustomlogin.model.LoginModel;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        logger.info("login get");
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/loginsubmit")
    public String loginsubmit(@ModelAttribute LoginModel user) {
        logger.info("login post");
        //model.addAttribute("username", login.getUsername());
        //model.addAttribute("password", login.getPassword());
        return "result";
    }

}
```

This is the SecurityClass:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@Profile("!https")
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                .permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click on submit button, the method "loginsubmit" of java controller is not called.

What can I do to fixed it

[image: EDIT]

This is the console log

Comment: Please include some debugging detail. Do you see the call from the browser console? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: I Just edit my question

Comment: Where does that 302 redirect to?

Comment: Anyway, if all paths require the user to be logged in, how do you expect the path you use to log the user in (apparently `/loginsubmit`) to work?

Comment: Your request is working exactly right.  You load the login page, your login form posts to an endpoint that is secured, your security filter intercepts the request and redirects you back to your login page.  To fix this, you simply need to add the endpoint `/loginsubmit` to your list of endpoints that are not secured, e.g. `.requestMatchers("/loginsubmit").permitAll()`